# Running text classification - CNN on GPU

Tags: deep-learning, gpu, text-classification, tensorflow

Based on this github link https://github.com/dennybritz/cnn-text-classification-tf , I want to classified my datasets on Ubuntu-16.04 on GPU.
For running on GPU, I've been changed line 23 on text_cnn.py to this : **with tf.device('*/gpu:0*'), tf.name_scope("embedding"):**

my **first dataset** for train phase has **9000 documents** and it's size is about **120M** and
**second one** for train has **1300 documents** and it's size is about **1M**.

**After running on my Titan X server with GPU, I have got errors.**
[image: img-3]

[image: img]

Please guide me, How can I solve this issue?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting Out of Memory error, so first thing to try is smaller batch size
(default is 64). I would start with:

`./train.py --batch_size 32`

Comment: I tried it with --batch_size 32 -- ./traint.py just working for 100 steps and after that with error it has been terminate.!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Most of the memory is used to hold the embedding parameters and convolution parameters. I would suggest reduce:

- `EMBEDDING_DIM`
- `NUM_FILTERS`
- `BATCH_SIZE`

try embedding_dim=16, batch_size=16 and num_filters=32, if that works, increase them 2x at a time.

Also if you are using docker virtual machine to run tensorflow, you might be limited to use only 1G of memory by default though you have 16G memory in your machine. see [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/136) for more details.